# Magento2: How to add placeholder in DOB field?

Tags: magento2, datepicker, magento2.4.3, magento-ui

Magento ver 2.4.3

I want to add placeholder on DOB field.

Please let me know the right way to add this.

Thanks

Comment: in checkout page??

Comment: on registration page

Answer (score 0):

below is path of magento block file which is calling $block->getFieldHtml()  method

> /vendor/magento/module-customer/Block/Widget/Dob.php

please override this method and add below code

I added **'placeholder' => 'Your PlaceHolder Text'** in below function

```
 public function getFieldHtml()
    {
        $this->dateElement->setData(
            [
                'extra_params' => $this->getHtmlExtraParams(),
                'name' => $this->getHtmlId(),
                'id' => $this->getHtmlId(),
                'class' => $this->getHtmlClass(),
                'value' => $this->getValue(),
                'date_format' => $this->getDateFormat(),
                'image' => $this->getViewFileUrl('Magento_Theme::calendar.png'),
                'years_range' => '-120y:c+nn',
                'max_date' => '-1d',
                'change_month' => 'true',
                'change_year' => 'true',
                'show_on' => 'both',
                'first_day' => $this->getFirstDay(),
                'placeholder' => 'Your PlaceHolder Text'
            ]
        );
        return $this->dateElement->getHtml();
    }
```

Note: Don't add directly in core file. it's bad practice and It will be reverted if you upgrade your magento version.

Answer (score 0):

you can override the block file

> vendor/magento/framework/View/Element/Html/Date.php

Create Date Class in your new module:

```
<?php
    /**
     * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
     * See COPYING.txt for license details.
     */
    namespace Vendor\Module\Model;
    
    /**
     * Date element block
     */
    class Date extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Date
    {
        /**
         * Render block HTML
         *
         * @return string
         * @SuppressWarnings(PHPMD.NPathComplexity)
         */
        protected function _toHtml()
        {
            $html = '<input placeholder="Your PlaceHolder Text" type="text" name="' . $this->getName() . '" id="' . $this->getId() . '" ';
            $html .= 'value="' . $this->escapeHtml($this->getValue()) . '" ';
            $html .= 'class="' . $this->getClass() . '" ' . $this->getExtraParams() . '/> ';
            $calendarYearsRange = $this->getYearsRange();
            $changeMonth = $this->getChangeMonth();
            $changeYear = $this->getChangeYear();
            $maxDate = $this->getMaxDate();
            $showOn = $this->getShowOn();
            $firstDay = $this->getFirstDay();
    
            $html .= '<script type="text/javascript">
                require(["jquery", "mage/calendar"], function($){
                        $("#' .
                $this->getId() .
                '").calendar({
                            showsTime: ' .
                ($this->getTimeFormat() ? 'true' : 'false') .
                ',
                            ' .
                ($this->getTimeFormat() ? 'timeFormat: "' .
                $this->getTimeFormat() .
                '",' : '') .
                '
                            dateFormat: "' .
                $this->getDateFormat() .
                '",
                            buttonImage: "' .
                $this->getImage() .
                '",
                            ' .
                ($calendarYearsRange ? 'yearRange: "' .
                $calendarYearsRange .
                '",' : '') .
                '
                            buttonText: "' .
                (string)new \Magento\Framework\Phrase(
                    'Select Date'
                ) .
                '"' . ($maxDate ? ', maxDate: "' . $maxDate . '"' : '') .
                ($changeMonth === null ? '' : ', changeMonth: ' . $changeMonth) .
                ($changeYear === null ? '' : ', changeYear: ' . $changeYear) .
                ($showOn ? ', showOn: "' . $showOn . '"' : '') .
                ($firstDay ? ', firstDay: ' . $firstDay : '') .
                '})
                });
                </script>';
    
            return $html;
        }
    }
```

Create di.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <preference for="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Date" type="Vendor\Module\Model\Date"/>
</config>
```

**Note**: you can add placeholder text according to your requirement in the above input field

**Example** : placeholder="Your PlaceHolder Text"

**ScreenShot** : https://prnt.sc/1vzmqj2

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    require([ 'jquery', 'jquery/ui'], function($){ 
      $(document).ready(function($) {
        jQuery("#dob").attr("placeholder", "Your PlaceHolder Text");
      }); 
    });
</script>
```